# Accessing Cookie client-side with Next JS

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

Using the [cookies-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next) package,
according to their docs, accessing cookies client side is as simple as `getCookie('key'); - client side`

I have a simple function in my Next JS app,

```
  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    const token = getCookie('cookie-token')

    console.log('token', token)
}
```

I see nothing is returned in the log. Although I do see the cookie does exist when checking my developer tools. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`next-client-cookies`](https://github.com/moshest/next-client-cookies) for Next.js 13 (app directory):

```js
'use client';

import { useCookies } from 'next-client-cookies';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const cookies = useCookies();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>My cookie value: {cookies.get('my-cookie')}</p>

      <button onClick={() => cookies.set('my-cookie', 'my-value')}>
        Set cookie
      </button>
      {' | '}
      <button onClick={() => cookies.delete('my-cookie')}>Delete cookie</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is currently the only solution for SSR cookies with Next v13.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package.

Comment: Thank you ! both for that answer and for your package 

Comment: I get this error using this package: https://github.com/moshest/next-client-cookies/issues/3

Comment: Hi Lonel, I don't think this issue related to the package. Please see more details on the issue.

Comment: Awesome package!

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js version 13, you could set/get the cookie in api functions with cookies-next. Cookie is generated when user logins.

### Install

```
pnpm i cookies-next
```

### Set Cookie

```
import { setCookie } from "cookies-next";

setCookie("cookieKey", value, { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 6 * 24 }); // then you can access the cookie in client-side
```

### Get Cookie

```
  import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

  const cookie = getCookie("cookieKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know that cookies have value, just refresh the page, and you can see them! but your cookies were of no value so first, check "setCookie"!

if you want to load in other components! you have to use "useEffect".

```
const token = getCookie('cookie-token')
const [myToken , setMyToken] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(token)
  setMyToken(token)
},[token])
console.log(myToken)
```

if you have SSR components:

```
export const getServerSideProps = ({ req, res }) => {
  const token = getCookie('cookie-token', { req, res });
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the set the cookie in api file before sending the response to the cookie. you set the token when user logins, so maybe in `pages/api/auth.signin` endpoint

```
import { setCookie } from "cookies-next";

const token=setTokenHere // what ever library you are using
// we tell client that, I want you to store this piece of information as a cookie
setCookie("jwt", token, { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 6 * 24 });
// then send the response object
return res.status(200).json({resObject
    });
```

on the client, whenever you need to access this cookie

```
 import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";
 // "jwt" is key, 
 const jwtToken = getCookie("jwt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the

> document.cookie

within useEffect, but still I'm not really sure if this is right to use in this case, since using document object is not recommended to use in React js. I'm just sharing my idea if this is ok to deal with. [Document: cookie property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Yea I think john had the best answer - I just made this util function

```
        export const getClientSideCookie = (name: string): string | undefined => {
            const cookieValue = document.cookie
                .split('; ')
                .find((row) => row.startsWith(`${name}=`))
                ?.split('=')[1];
        
           return cookieValue;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acces directly with **document.cookie**, and you will receive as a response a string with all cookies. For example:

```
const myCookies = document.cookie 
console.log(myCookies)
```

More details in this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/javascript-developer-guide-browser-cookies/).